# Marginal Distribution of Diffusion Process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Working on a problem that I'm having some trouble starting. I have $X_t = 2t + 3B_t$ for $t \ge 0$ where $B_t$ is a Brownian Motion. I want to find the marginal distribution of $X_t$, as well as $E(X_s * X_t)$ for $s < t$. I'm pretty sure for the marginal distribution I need to apply Ito's formula, but I'm not exactly sure where to do this. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you can represent your process as an OU process and use its properties. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process

Comment: "[...]I'm pretty sure for the marginal distribution I need to apply Ito's formula" No, you don't. If $U \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ then what is the distribution of $aU+b$ (for constants $a >0$, $b \in \mathbb{R}$)...?

Comment: Does this mean it would just be a normal distribution with mean 2t and variance 3t?

Comment: The mean is correct but the variance is not.

Comment: Oops, forgot to square. Think I have it now. Thank you!